# Is there any difference between the Java and C++ operators?

Tags: java, c++, operators

If you take Java's primitive numeric types, plus boolean, and compare it to C++ equivalent types, is there any difference what concerns the operators, like precedence rules or what the bit-manipulation operators do? Or the effect of parenthesis?

Asked another way, if I took a Java expression and tried to compile and run it in C++, would it always compile and always give the same result?

Comment: I think something different happens when you cast ie (int). I seem to recall that you may get compile errors that you would not get in C.

Comment: 'm not sure I understand you. Do you mean something compiles in C that does not in Java? That would be OK for me. But the other way around would be a problem.

Comment: Yes something compiles in C that Java's coercion would not allow. I tried to figure out what it was last night... damn my memory.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- For an expression like:

  ```
  a = foo() + bar();
  ```

  In Java, the evaluation order is well-defined (left to right).  C++ does not specify whether `foo()` or `bar()` is evaluated first.
- Stuff like:

  ```
  i = i++;
  ```

  is undefined in C++, but again well-defined in Java.
- In C++, performing right-shifts on negative numbers is implementation-defined/undefined; whereas in Java it is well-defined.
- Also, in C++, the operators `&`, `|` and `^` are purely bitwise operators.  In Java, they can be bitwise or logical operators, depending on the context.

Comment: @Lazarus: You're right, side-effects (which is what I was thinking about) are somewhat outside the scope of the question.  Unless, of course, the side effects of `foo` affect the result of `bar`, or vice versa.

Comment: @Lazarus: In terms of the post-increment, C++ works in terms of [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).  There are two modifications to `i`, but no intermediate sequence point, so the result is undefined.

Comment: An interesting piece on sequence points but let's face it, your post-increment statement isn't just an edge-case, it's an off the edge case ;)

Answer (score 5):

Java specifies more about the order of evaluation of expressions than C++, and C++ says that you get undefined behavior if *any* of the legal evaluation orders of your expression modify an object twice between sequence points.

So, `i++ + i++` is well defined in Java, but has undefined behavior (no diagnosis required) in C++. Therefore you can't blindly copy expressions from Java to C++.

For bitwise operators, Java specifies two's-complement representation of negative numbers whereas C++ doesn't. Not that you're *likely* to encounter another representation in C++, but if you did then you would find for example that `-2 | 1` is always `-1` in Java, but is `-2` in a C++ implementation using 1s' complement.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that operator precedence is consistent between C++ and Java and provided the expression is deterministic then it should evaluate the same way.

Comment: Agreed, there is the bitwise operators which I'm not familiar with in Java but providing the >> was translated to >>> the precedence of operators in an expression involving only primitives (as indicated by the OP) would surely still be fairly consistent (assuming the implementations followed spec).

Answer (score 1):

The right-shift operator `>>` is different. In Java it's always an arithmetic shift, i.e. it copies the sign bit into the leftmost bit, whereas in C++ it's implementation-defined whether it's an arithmetic or logical shift. You can get a logical shift in Java using `>>>`, which doesn't exist in C++.

Comment: Does implementation-define mean per-compiler, or per-OS? If I test gcc on Windows, will it word the same on Linux? Or can't I rely on that either?

Comment: You just need to read the documentation for your compiler. Most modern compilers will give you an arithmetic right-shift for signed integers,  so I'd be surprised if gcc behaves differently on Windows and Linux, but you just need to read the docs to be certain.

Answer (score 1):

See this:

> int a = 0;
>
> int b = (a++) + (a);

If you print `b` then it will output `0` in C++ whereas `1` in Java

Answer (score 0):

There must be lot of difference, because in Java almost all numeric types are always signed. Read Java Puzzlers book and Java Language Specification to understand all the subtle differences.